# Problems debugging Ruby in VSCode - debugger not executing AND can not display variables

Tags: ruby, visual-studio-code, debugging

Both of theses cost me a couple of hours each hoping to save someone else the headache

Rather than a question this is the SOLUTIONS to 2 Ruby VSCode debug problems I had.

1. Debugger would only intermittently start and the program would not run to completion but would run to completion if selected run without debugging.   Had upgraded from Ruby 2.? to
   Ruby 3.2 just prior.  This was a prev working program.  This is probably well documented someplace but i did not see it.

Had to **disable 'Ruby Debug Env' extension and enable 'VSCode rdgb' extension.**
This resolved my problems.

2. had a running program in which i lost the ability to display variables either by hovering over them or using watch.  Eventually traced to system command `dir root_folder` which after execution I could no longer display variables for remainder of program.  %x[] also caused same problem.
   Changed command to "Dir.entries root_folder" to get around problem.

Answer (score 0):

Both of theses cost me a couple of hours each. Just hoping the above saves someone else the headache.

NOTE "dir root_folder" is enclosed in back ticks which are apparently not displayed